# Algorithm For Giving HashTags Suggestion

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, algorithm

I am working on a React project and there is a text area in it. The user types his post in it and like any simple social media, adds tags in his post in format `#tagName`

So whenever he starts writing hashtags, I fetch some suggestions from server and display them below the textbox in form of chips. And similarly when he clicks on them, they get appended to the text.

The problem I am facing is that I want to minimize the fetch request so that it is user friendly.

Things to keep in mind :

1. I will fetch only if the tag's length is at least 3 characters.
2. I will fetch only once for a tag.
3. There is a possibility that the tag does not exist. So I have to check that and call different API to create that.

```
// If you don't know React just think the useRef() as nothing just a way to define global variables
// that will never loose their values.
// and the variable's value is accessed as variable.current
// event.target.value is the text of the textarea or simply our post
```

My code looks like this

```
  const [statusText, setStatusText] = useState("");
  const [tagsSuggestion, setTagsSuggestion] = useState([]);
  const [displaySuggestion, setDisplaySuggestion] = useState([]);

  let isTag = useRef(false);
  let tagIndex = useRef(0);
  let lastTag = useRef("");
  let userTags = useRef([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let searchText = event.target.value;
    setStatusText(searchText);

    let lastWord = searchText.charAt(searchText.length - 1);

    if (lastWord === "#") {
      isTag.current = true;
      tagIndex.current = searchText.length;
      if (lastTag.current.length) lastTag.current = "";
    }

    if (lastWord === " ") {
      isTag.current = false;
      if (lastTag.current.length) checkIfPushed(lastTag.current);
      lastTag.current = "";
      return;
    }

    if (isTag.current && lastWord !== "#") {
      lastTag.current = searchText.substring(tagIndex.current);
    }

    if (lastTag === "") setTagsZero();

    if (isTag.current && lastTag.current.length === 2) {
      fetchSuggestion(lastTag.current);
      return;
    }

    if (isTag.current && lastTag.current.length > 2) {
      let suggestion = tagsSuggestion.filter(
        (tag, index) => tag.name.startsWith(lastTag.current) && index < 5
      );
      setDisplaySuggestion(suggestion);
    }
  };
```

What I do is I save all the tags in tagSuggestion and then filter the tags to show in displaySuggestion

But it is buggy and dies when the user presses backspace.

Please suggest me an alternative algorithm. It should be highly optimized as you know programmers type fast and we can't use the javascript functions like split, slice, they take too much time. My code has O(1) for every character entered

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many tags are there in total?

Comment: I don't know how many tags there will be in the text or will come from server. The limit for the post is 400 characters. Including tags, spaces and symbols.

Comment: Well, check with the backend devs or third party dev team for the total number of tags. I had trie data structure in my mind to show for suggestions as the prefix has to be same while typing.

Comment: With trie(if possible), you can eliminate fetching from server on each keypress.

Comment: there are approx 100 tags and they will increase in number as we can create a new tag

Comment: Then it's doable. _There is a possibility that the tag does not exist. So I have to check that and call different API to create that._ You just check that insert them in the backend after a form post. Don't create it while typing.